# AWS S3 put event Lambda create DynamoDB entry with correct owner Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using amplify Storage client JS library in order to put a file on S3.

```
    this.amplify.storage().put( 
            this.s3ImagePath,
        this.s3ImageFile, 
        this._storageOptions)
```

On the s3 I have created a trigger for the `PUT` events in order to call a Lambda.
The Lambda inserts an entry on DynamoDB.
My problem is that I want to put the correct owner at this newly created DynamoDB entry.

Inside the Lambda I call the headObject like this:

```
    const headResult = await S3.headObject({Bucket: bucketName, Key: key }).promise();
    console.log('headResult ', headResult);
```

I would expect that the `headResult` would contain the correct owner who uploaded the file and created the event on S3 bucket.
I am able to find from the S3 event:

```
ownerIdentity: { principalId: 'A2N3MUDHGLOEZI' },
```

but I am not sure how to use this in order to find the correct owner and insert the correct value on the new DynamoDB entry.

I found also this that could help:

```
userIdentity: 
{ principalId: 'AWS:AROASQSLQMXWXMMOH3FEA:CognitoIdentityCredentials' },
```

Since I am new to the serverless paradigm could you please tell me how am I supposed to insert a new entry to the DynamoDB when the Lambda is triggered from an S3 PUT event ?

As a workaround I am thinking to remove the S3 PUT event that calls the lambda in order to create the entry and call a mutation from the client when the upload of the file finishes. But I consider this a workaround and not the correct approach to the problem.